# Need opposite to field__lte

Tags: django

In my application i need the opposite to the `date_of_talk__lte=` as this results in `where date_of_talk <=` and I need this and this so should I just execute one query using `model.objects.raw(query)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `date_of_talk__gte`?

Comment: Thanks, i couldn't see it in the Django Docs.

Comment: Possibly _gt, as _gte is Greater Than or Equal